# edge.js using node module

Tags: node.js, edge.js

I'm trying the following with edge.js and Visual Studio:

```
class Program
{
    public static async void Start()
    {
        var data = 9;
        var func = Edge.Func(File.ReadAllText("do_some_math.js"));
        Console.WriteLine(await func(data));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
    }
}
```

do_some_math.js:

```
return function (data, callback) {

    var math = require('mathjs');    

    // console.log("result: " + math.sqrt(data));  // works
    callback(null, "result: " + math.sqrt(data));  

}
```

I can't get a result when using callback, while mathjs works when using console.log. It seems the callback does not work after require('mathjs'). I tryed also with other modules. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/391), they provided the answer. I guess this should have been a question about C#. They answered:

The reason you are not getting a result is that the .NET application exits before the Node.js code has a chance to complete. You can verify it by putting `System.Threading.Sleep(5000);` as the last statement in Main.

The way to address it properly (i.e. without Sleep) is to modify the signature of `Start` to

```
public static async Task Start()
```

And then in Main call it with:

```
Start().Wait();
```